# Getting data from selecteditem wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, datagrid, textbox

I'm trying to get this Data item from my SelectedItem.

I use a DataGrid called grd. Which is a custom datagrid extended on the normal datagrid.

But I want to put the value 'DATA' in a textBox so I can find out the caret index.

[image]

My code so far:

```
private void Selected_TextBox_Index (Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

      FileEditorDataGrid grd = (FileEditorDataGrid)sender;
      TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
      textBox.Text = grd.SelectedItem.ToString();
      DataRowView dataRow;
      Int32 selectedIndex;

      selectedIndex = grd.SelectedIndex;
      dataRow = grd.Items.GetItemAt(selectedIndex) as DataRowView;

      Int64 cursorPos = textBox.CaretIndex;
      if (ViewModel.TextBoxCursorCommand.CanExecute(null)) {
        ViewModel.TextBoxCursorCommand.Execute(cursorPos);

      }
    } // Selected_TextBox_Index
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by using:

```
 var dataInTheItem = selectedItem.GetType().GetProperty("Data").GetValue(grd.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use reflection here. Just cast the property.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the `SelectedItem` to your data type and access the property directly:

```
 var dataInTheItem = (grd.SelectedItem as YourClass)?.Data;
```

This is better than using reflection, both when it comes to maintainability and readability as well as performance.